# Output ascii characters to stdout in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I have a file named 'xxx.py' like this:

```
print("a simple string")
```

and when I run that like this (Python 3):

```
python xxx.py >atextfile.txt
```

I get a unicode file.

I would like an ascii file.

I don't mind if an exception is thrown if a non-ascii character is attempted to be printed.

What is a simple change I can make to my code that will output ascii characters?

My searches turn up solutions that all seem too verbose for such a simple problem.

[Edit] to report what I learned from setting LC_CTYPE:

I am running on windows 7.

1. When running on the powershell commandline I get a unicode file (two bytes/character)
2. When running in a .bat file without LC_CTYPE set I get an ascii file (could be utf-8 as @jwodder pointed out).
3. When running in a .bat file with LC_CTYPE=ascii set I get presumable an ascii file (1 byte/character).

Comment: How is `printf()` defined? The standard encoding is likely defined by the locale of the shell that executed `xxx.py`. You could try `LC_TYPE=en_us python xxx.py > atextfile.txt`. Check the value of `sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: All ASCII files are Unicode (specifically, UTF-8) files.  Exactly what about `atextfile.txt` are you trying to change?  Is it in one of the non-ASCII-compatible Unicode encodings, like UTF-16?

Comment: what is `print(sys.stdout)`? What is `print(open('atextfile.txt', 'rb').read())`? What is `print(locale.getpreferredencoding())`? Please, do not call a file with a text encoded using the utf-16 character encoding "a unicode file". A Unicode string has no associated character encoding in Python—you can encode the same Unicode string into bytes  using multiple encodings. A file on disk is a stream of bytes that sometimes can be interpreted as text given an appropriate character encoding.

Comment: That setting `LC_CTYPE` -- or any `LC_` environment variable -- would affect anything on *Windows* makes no sense. The Windows locale is configured in the control panel and via API calls, not environment variables. There's nothing in either the CRT code or CPython's code that looks at these environment variables on Windows. The stdout encoding either comes from `GetConsoleOutputCP()` when stdout is a tty, or it defaults to `locale.getpreferredencoding()`, which ultimately gets the encoding from `GetACP()`, the system ANSI codepage.

Answer (score 1):

The `stdout` encoding is defined by the environment that is executing the python script, e.g.:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"
UTF-8
$ LC_CTYPE=ascii python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"
US-ASCII
```

Try adjusting your environment before running the script. You can force the encoding value for Python by setting the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable.